# After installing python 3.7.2 usr/bin has only python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, python-3.7

I am new to python and I have just installed [python 3.7.2](https://www.python.org/downloads/), at least that is what my IDLE tells me. However, when I check my usr/bin, I see python2.7 only. Why is that? What's going on?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: this is first and only python that my machine had seen, I am pretty sure.

System: IOS v.10.13.6

Comment: Run `which python3.7`. It should tell you where your new Python is. Probably `/usr/local/bin`, or somewhere in your home directory.

Comment: It almost certaily installed it somewhere else, but our guesses will depend enormously on what platform you're on and how you installed it. For a start, can we assume you actually mean `/usr/bin` with a slash in front?

Comment: This question is not for StackOverflow but a different Stack Exchange site. What happens when you type `python` on the command line and press Tab? You should see the list of available Python versions, then use the `which` command.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks! Ok, it is in a different location. But the fact that I have python2.7 not 3.7 in usr/bin is problem. For instance if I supply Xcode with a building tool, I usually refer to usr/bin/"tool", but python2.7 that I have there is the wrong tool...

Comment: @tripleee You are absolutely right. It somehow has python 2.7 from 2017. I have to repost the question now, I guess...

Comment: Why wouldn't IOS have a Python installation by default? Python is used in quite a few system management scripts, and IOS probably makes use of at least a couple of them.

Comment: @9769953 well, citing the terminal: "Python  2.7.10 (default, Oct 6 2017, ...)" I did not instal it for sure. Don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now a days, **MAC OS X** comes with `python2` pre-installed and they make it available for use by placing it in in `/usr/local/bin` and this location is already in the **System PATH**.

If you install any new version like **Python3+** it installs on `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/<version>/bin/`.

E.g. In my case, the fullpath is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3` & `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6`.

I have installed **Python3.6** using **Homebrew**.

Below are the helpful logs of my terminal. Please have a look.

> » Versions check with path (**which python**)

```
Rishikeshs-MacBook-Air:~ hygull$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
Rishikeshs-MacBook-Air:~ hygull$
```

> **which python3**

```
Rishikeshs-MacBook-Air:~ hygull$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
Rishikeshs-MacBook-Air:~ hygull$
```

> **which python3.6**

```
Rishikeshs-MacBook-Air:~ hygull$ which python3.6
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6
Rishikeshs-MacBook-Air:~ hygull$
```

> » Start & exit (python2, default installation on MAC OS X)
>
> **python**

```
Rishikeshs-MacBook-Air:~ hygull$ python
Python 2.7.15 (default, Jan 12 2019, 21:07:57) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> exit()
Rishikeshs-MacBook-Air:~ hygull$
```

> **python3**

```
Rishikeshs-MacBook-Air:~ hygull$ python3
Python 3.6.7 (v3.6.7:6ec5cf24b7, Oct 20 2018, 03:02:14) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> exit()
Rishikeshs-MacBook-Air:~ hygull$
```

> **python3.6**
>
> (Same as above but useful if you have two **python3+**, e.g. if you have **python3.6** & **python3.7** installed & you want to work with **python3.6**)

```
Rishikeshs-MacBook-Air:~ hygull$ python3.6
Python 3.6.7 (v3.6.7:6ec5cf24b7, Oct 20 2018, 03:02:14) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```